# Directory highlighted in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I just enabled coloring for ls command but for some reason few directories are highlighted, which bugs me because I don't know why.

Could someone tell me how to disable it or why they are highlighted?

[image]

```
ls -l ~/:
drwx------   3 hungig  staff   102B Oct 20 14:06 Applications/
drwx------+ 12 hungig  staff   408B Apr  6 13:23 Desktop/
drwx------+  9 hungig  staff   306B Apr  6 23:24 Documents/
drwx------+ 14 hungig  staff   476B Apr  6 22:38 Downloads/
drwxr-xr-x   6 hungig  staff   204B Mar 27 16:59 IdeaProjects/
drwx------+ 67 hungig  staff   2.2K Jan  5 19:27 Library/
drwx------+  5 hungig  staff   170B Jan 28  2016 Movies/
drwx------+  4 hungig  staff   136B Jan 26  2016 Music/
drwx------+  5 hungig  staff   170B Feb  4 16:21 Pictures/
drwxr-xr-x+  5 hungig  staff   170B Jan 26  2016 Public/
drwxrwxrwx  16 hungig  staff   544B Mar  6 12:28 Qt/
```

**Env variables of interest**

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$
export CLICOLOR=YES
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

Comment: Please add your bash coloring scheme and the output of `ls -l ~/`to your question (as text - not as screenshot)!

Comment: Probably driven by permissions, does `Qt` have other permissions?

Comment: Please look at the output of `ls -lG /private/`. Is `tmp` has the same color?

Answer (score 3):

The (background and foreground) color of the folder Qt in your *ls* output is determined by the last two pairs in your ls color scheme: ExFxBxDxCxegedabag**acad** because it's world writable.

```
drwxrwxrwx  16 hungig  staff   544B Mar  6 12:28 Qt/
        ↑↑
        |but no sticky bit (a sticky bit would be indicated by a "t")
        world writeable
```

The last (=11th) pair colorizes **directories writable to others but without sticky bit**. The color scheme as indicated by your LSCOLORS env variable is a=black foreground and d=brown background. To set it to your default directory color simply change it to ...Ex.

---

Applying the posted color scheme (PS1 & LSCOLORS and assuming user *[Davos Doe](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/232190/davos-doe)* = user *[Hung Hoang](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/232301/hung-hoang)*, who posted the scheme as well as the ls output in an answer, which got deleted and is visible to users with a reputation of ≥ 10,000 only) in a default Terminal shell I get almost completely different color effects though.

[image]